# After Emptying an Array, the Code Isn't Reading That It's Empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js, fs

I'm trying to send temporary information to a json file where I can store them as an array of objects and then after some time, automatically reset the file back to an empty array.

The code reads fine at first and stores the information, but once it sets back to an empty array, the code no longer reads that it's empty and still does things when it shouldn't. When using the join command below it's supposed to check if it's empty and return if it is and not store anything until there is an enemy in there first. The response of "user joined the fight" still happens and nothing is stored in the array.

Here is the join command

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const enemySpawn = require('../EnemySpawn.json');
const { rpgbot } = require('../colors.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'join',
    description: 'Used to join the grouping of players to fight an enemy that spawns',
    execute(message, args) {
        if (enemySpawn.length == 0) return message.channel.send('There\'s no enemy to fight!');
        if (enemySpawn.some(user => user.id === message.author.id)) return message.channel.send('You already joined the current fight!');

        // TODO add users stats 
        enemySpawn.push({
            name: message.author.username,
            id: message.author.id
        })

        fs.writeFile('./EnemySpawn.json', JSON.stringify(enemySpawn), err => {
            if (err) console.error(err);
        });

        // TODO add current level of the user
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(rpgbot)
        .addField(`${message.author.username} joined the fight!`, '\u200B')

        message.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

Here is the function of getting the enemy and storing it first

```
const fs = require('fs');

const enemySpawn = require('./EnemySpawn.json');
const enemies = require('./Enemies.json')

getEnemy: function (message) {
        if (!(enemySpawn.length == 0)) return;

        let randomEnemy = enemies[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemies.length)];

        enemySpawn.push({
            enemy: randomEnemy.name,
            health: randomEnemy.health
        })

        fs.writeFile('./EnemySpawn.json', JSON.stringify(enemySpawn), err => {
            if (err) console.error(err);
        });

        message.channel.send(`Watch out! A ${randomEnemy.name} appeared!`);
    }
```

And here is where it is called when someone sends a message which also has a timeout function to clear the array after 3 seconds for testing

```
const fs = require('fs');

const functions = require('./functions.js');

let used = false;

if (!used) {
        functions.getEnemy(message);
        used = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            used = false;
            fs.writeFile('./EnemySpawn.json', JSON.stringify([]), err => {
                if (err) console.error(err);
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
```

Comment: Consider re-writting the question focusing on just the issue. Abstract the unnecessary code and focus on the array that does not empty.

Answer (score 0):

The only places I see you reading the json file is with this:

```
const enemySpawn = require('../EnemySpawn.json');
```

and both of those are in module initialization which will only ever be executed once at startup.  So, after you write the empty array back to the file, you don't ever read it back again (unless you restart your server).

If you want that empty array to be read back in again, you have to actually read that JSON file again in real time during some operation.

Comment: So you're saying instead of having it as an initialization at the top I have to put that inside the actual function to be read every time when the functions are called?

Comment: @QuazArxx - If what you're trying to do is to get the latest contents of the file before executing the function, then yes you will need to read the latest contents of the file inside the function.  It isn't clear to me at all why you don't just store this info in a module-level variable and share that.  Why do you have to be constantly reading and writing it to a file?

Comment: Just seem to be an easy way to store the objects so I can get the information for later for other functions I'll be using. Especially since my command "join" is stored in a separate folder and sending it all to 1 file together seemed to be the way to go.

Comment: @QuazArxx - The module design of node.js makes it easy for you to have a module that "owns" the array and exports it.  Any other module who wants to use the array can import it.  As long as you just modify the existing array and don't assign it a new, separate array, all holders of the original array will see all modifications to it (true sharing of the data).  You can read/write to a file if you want, but it is not necessary just to share data between a couple modules.  You should be using the file system when you need persistence of data across a server crash or restart.

Comment: I've used this method before for storing information that was constantly read and updated and I never had an issue with it until it came to emptying it out now. I have a level system and a currency system using the exact same way. I figured I could keep using this same way except with a temporary array that will change it's contents.

Comment: How would I then store the users with properties as a temporary variable to be used in multiple functions?

Comment: @QuazArxx - Well, a `require()` at the top level of your module is only ever executed once when the module is first loaded.  If you want it executed regularly as part of some function execution, you have to read the data inside some function that is called as part of your operation and you should not be using `require()` during run-time either because it's synchronous/blocking.  You would use `fs.readFile()` and then parse the JSON.

Comment: @QuazArxx - Let one module "own" the array.  That module then declares it locally at the top level of the module and exports it.  Anyone else who wants access to it, then imports it from that module.  That will provide a pointer to the original array which will automatically see all modifications to it.  Just don't ever reassign the whole array to a new array as that will break the link with the previous export.  You can modify the array to your heart's content, just don't assign it a new array.  For example, to empty it, you would do `sharedArray.length = 0`, not `sharedArray = [];`.

Comment: When I use the “sharedArray.length = 0” way it just puts a 0 as the whole file. I want to empty the array to leave the file with just [ ] so I can push information to it

Comment: @QuazArxx - `sharedArray.length = 0` will set the in-memory array by the name `sharedArray` to be an empty array.  It has nothing at all to do with the file unless you also write that to the file.  I don't really understand what your comment means.

Comment: Literally just doing sharedArray.length = 0 removes everything and just puts 0 in the file and nothing else

Comment: @QuazArxx - You'd have to show the actual code you're talking about because it sounds like sharedArray is not an array then.  I was just using that as a psuedo-code name for an array you were sharing and NOT writing to your file.  I'm totally confused about what you are or aren't doing any more.  I think I've given you the advice I can give you relative to your original question.  If you have some new implementation that you want to ask about, perhaps it makes sense to write a new question and show that new code.

Comment: I know that's why you were using that variable. That's why I used it back to you. I parsed the array as a variable. I used that variable with ".length = 0" and I messed up on what was happening but nothing is happening. Array isn't emptying, no errors are showing on the console. The data still stays in the array. I'm not writing a new question since this question hasn't been answered even with the given advice. Thanks though

Comment: @QuazArxx - Well, I can't answer questions based on some implementation you've done that you aren't showing.  If you want further help from me on your implementation, you have to show the code exactly as it is now.  If you don't know this, you would use the "edit" link and ADD it to the end of your question, leaving the original code in place at the start of the question.  Only if you do that, can I have any chance of helping further.

Comment: @QuazArxx - My suggestion was to not even save anything to the file, but to use a shared array in memory instead - it does not sound like that's what you're doing since you keep talking about your file.  So, at this point, I don't know what you're doing without seeing the latest version of the code.  I can't tell if you didn't understand my suggestion or just made your own modifications to do something different.